# Multi-char delimiter while performing CTAS - HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, delimiter, create-table, delimited

I am trying to create a table (CTAS) and I want it to have a multi-char delimiter to it like let’s say “#$“ or “^|^“.

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_name> 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="@#")
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
AS 
SELECT <columns> from <table> ;
```

While running it, is throwing NullPointerException:

```
ERROR : Job failed with java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Exception thrown by job
    at org.apache.spark.JavaFutureActionWrapper.getImpl(FutureAction.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.JavaFutureActionWrapper.get(FutureAction.scala:342)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:362)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver$JobWrapper.call(RemoteDriver.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, agent3659-phx3.prod.uber.internal, executor 1): java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{},"value":{"_col0":"<column_value>"}}
```

I have also tried RegexSerDe, same error.

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "^(\\d+)~\\*(.*)$")
```

Will be great to get your inputs on this.

Comment: You are trying to create table from another table whereas assuming new table will be based on a file. can you try to create just the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little lost.  Why are you even using a file format specification if the data is already in a table?  Just use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_name> 
    SELECT <columns> 
    FROM <table> ;
```

Comment: I just gave select * as an example, the real intention is to create another table (file will be sent to the vendor) with these multi-char delimiters.